# Perl: Declare a scalar variable using a text string from another scalar variable

Tags: perl

I'm really new to Perl and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to declare a scalar variable using a text string from another scalar variable.

I have an array which has contains a range of years, based on input provided by the user. I need to open files contained in directories which correspond to those years. So for instance, if the user entered the year range 1990-1999, I will need to open and assign a file handle for the years 1990, 1991, ..., 1998.

I imagined using something like the following, replacing `[year]` with `$_`:

```
foreach (@year_range)
{
    my $[year]_file = "assets/[year]/file.csv";
    open my $[year]_handle, "<", $[year]_file or die "$[year]_file: $!";
}

[do stuff]
[close files using the reverse of above]
```

Unfortunately, thats not working out too well. Is there anyway that I could make the above work, or is there some other way to open files and assign file handles when their name's are unknown before runtime?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**

Thank you everyone for your feedback, I would give you upvotes if my rep was high enough.

I had a feeling that opening so many files at a time was probably not the best idea so what I ended up doing was opening the files in a loop, pulling what I the information that I needed, closing the files, and repeating as necessary, reusing the same handle.

After only really programming in C, it took me a while to get my head around Perl's scalars and arrays-- I didn't even know that hashes where a thing, but I'm finding them pretty useful, thanks for the tip Sobrique.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to have all the files open at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a hash to hold your file handles, like this

```
my %fh;

for my $year ( @year_range ) {
    my $dir = "assets/$year";
    mkdir $dir
    open $fh{$year}, '>', "$dir/file.csv" or die $!;
}
```

But, as TLP says, is there a reason why you need all of the files open simultaneously?

Comment: Looking back, no, probably not. When I posted this I had just started out programming and approached the problem naively. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

I will take a bit of a tangent as you already have some answers. What you are trying to do here is called a symbolic reference.

It won't work if you turn on `strict` for a simple reason - it's a bad idea and it's unnecessary.

You see, by allowing dynamic variable names like that, you introduce the possibility of tampering with key variables elsewhere in your program accidentally. This is a great way of making bugs which are amazingly difficult to troubleshoot and track down.

More importantly - it's not necessary, because you can use hashes - as Borodin points out in his solution. A hash is a portable namespace - it allows you to do 'key-value' type relationships in a way that *isn't* going to trash somewhere else in your program.

At a simplistic level:

```
my %filehandles;

open ( $filehandles{$year}, "<", "file_to_read ) or die;
```

And you can access the 'years' in the hash with:

```
keys %filehandles;
```

Or the handles with:

```
values %filehandles;
```

For a little more context, take a look here:
http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

Answer (score 0):

```
my @files=();
my @fhs=();
my $i=0;
foreach my $year (@year_range)
{
    local *FH;
    $files[$i] = "assets/".$year."/file.csv";
    open FH, "<", $files[$i] or die "$files[$i]: $!";
    push(@fhs, *FH);
    $i++; 
}
```

Eventually you need just one list (fh), if you don't use names of the files.

Comment: Why are you using an array of file handles here, when a hash is a much more appropriate data structure?